# Lazy fibonnaci series

Tags: java, c#, scala, haskell, fibonacci

I have just started learning haskell and wondering if there is any way we can implement below fibonacci series in C# or java or other non-lazy imperative languages.

In haskell we can succinctly generate fibonacci series with the below one liner

> fibonacci = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibonacci (tail fibonacci)

Question - I understand that as C#/Java etc eagerly evaluates, the above would probably go to an infinite loop. But what i do not understand is that even if we use a thunk, how can we can create a self referencing data structure which changes as we iterate over it **(using recursion)**.

Appreciate if you could share some snippet

Comment: Apologies, Maybe I should have been explicit, I am looking from the imperative side of it. Stream would be functional approach. I want to better understand if i were to write this in imperative language how would i code it? Could you try explaining the same using imperative data structure/or the impure side of scala?

Comment: C# has "yield return" construct that is designed to defer execution until the result is request. So it is not "eagerly evaluates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Scala API docs for Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) contains an example on how to do this in Scala:

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }
```

Edit: To implement memoization in a language which doesn't have it built-in like Haskell, you would obviously need to use mutation (an array or a map). For example:

```
  val fib: Int => Int = {
    val m = ArrayBuffer(0, 1)

    x => if (x < m.size) m(x) else {
      println("Calculating " + x + "...")
      val r = fib(x - 2) + fib(x - 1)
      m += r
      r
    }
  }
```

This can still be considered to be a pure function as there are no observable side effects (besides runtime performance) in a single threaded environment.

Comment: Thanks that helps. I just wanted to confirm if there is any other way of doing it without a backing data structure.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can implement this in the next way:

```
IEnumerable <int> Fibonacci() {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 1;
    while (true) {
        var t = b;
        yield return b = a + b;
        a = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry there is no recursion here

Comment: Sorry, but recursion is not a great idea in languages that don't do tail recursion optimization.

Comment: That's exactly the point. The function that you provided in Haskell is just an example of tail call. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Comment: The piece of code above does exactly what the Haskell example above. It consists of two things. It execute the body of that function in the loop and passes the result of previous iteration to the next. The Haskell recursive syntax is just a syntax sugar for it. The second thing it returns enumerator. Which makes the loop to go through the cycle only when you request the next element.

Comment: Yes i understand what tail call optimization  and yield return based generator does etc is. My question is not regarding best practice/performance optimization or what is wrong or right, i just wanted to know if we need a backing data structure or not if we were to recursively call a function and generate the series via self referencing data structure as haskell does. Please read my question again, i wanted to know about self referencing data structure (kind of a chicken and egg problem)

Comment: @RohitSharma this answer *is useful* as it demonstrates the functionally equivalent code implementing the same inductive process. You only *strictly* need the backing store in [*strong* induction](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~stephens/203/PDF/4-4.pdf). Of course the store comes in handy when you want to reuse it; but it isn't strictly necessary here with the limited back-reference. Here, there *is* a backing store, unraveled into two variables, as that's all that's needed to go on forward.

Comment: @RohitSharma I meant *growing, unbounded in size* backing store (for strong induction), obviously.